# How to Replace some value of First Row as "-" in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have below mentioned dataframe:

```
Month   ID   V1   V2    V3     V4     V5     V6    V7
Mar-17  1    2    3.5%  4      6      8      1.5%  15
Feb-17  1    2    2.5%  2      3      5      5.5%  15
Jan-17  1    2    7.5%  1      8      1      3.5%  15
```

I want to replace `V2`, `V4` and `V6` as "-" of the dataframe for the first row only.

Comment: `df[, c(4, 6, 8)] <- "-"`?

Comment: @jaySf I just want to change it for only first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[1, c("V2", "V4", "V6")] <- "-"
```